# How to prevent route rendering before user authentication with Svelte 4 and SvelteKit using local storage?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm working on a web application using Svelte 4 and SvelteKit, and I want to implement user authentication on the client-side using local storage. My goal is to redirect users to the login route before rendering the protected routes. However, I'm facing an issue where the protected routes are still being rendered before the redirection happens.

What would be the best approach to handle user authentication efficiently and prevent unnecessary rendering of protected routes? I'd appreciate any guidance or code examples on how to achieve this seamlessly.

Comment: Isn't [that](https://www.reddit.com/r/sveltejs/comments/zwntvc/handling_authentication_with_sveltekit/) (which link to [that](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K1Tya6ovVOI) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UbhhJWV3bmI) video) what you want ?

Comment: The protected routes are being rendered because sveltekit gets the localStorage values after it has loaded +layout.svelte; then redirects.  You could get rid of this by using a something like a splash screen to disable display of the <slot/> until after store value is got;  It is however better to use cookies for auth as you will see in @Poulpynator 's comment

Comment: Are you using static-adapter? If not, why not use a secure server cookie to do this so you can access and manage it in your +server/+page.server/+layout.server code? If you want it to be an SPA you're going to need to wait till local storage returns data so youll want to prevent loading of those pages as Natumanya says above.